# Android binding - get all EditText values

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-edittext

I have an activity, with EditText fields. A use data binding, so I can get String value from EditText like this:

```
binding.printWidth.getText().toString()
```

Is there a way to get all id's and values from all EditText in activity? Something like:

```
for (int a=0;a<binding.EditCount;a++)
{
list.add(binding.edit(a).id,binding.edit(a).value);
}
```

I understand, that I can use classic way, like:

```
ArrayList<EditText> myEditTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
for( int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount(); i++ )
  if( myLayout.getChildAt( i ) instanceof EditText )
    myEditTextList.add( (EditText) myLayout.getChildAt( i ) );
```

But is tere a way to do something like this with databinding?